# Passing functions via array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular js and still working on things. I would like to ask if it's possible to initiate ng-click variables (which are functions.) in angular js? Here is as snippet of my code

```
<div data-ng-controller="DeathRayController">
    <button data-ng-click="toggleMenu()">Toggle Menu</button>
    <ul ng-show="menuState.show">
        <li data-ng-repeat="menu in menuList"><a href="" data-ng-click="menu.mode">{{ menu.value }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my controller using angularjs:

```
var showHide = angular.module('showHide', []);

showHide.controller('DeathRayController', function ($scope) {
// the idea is to display this on the <a ng-click="menu.mode">
    $scope.menuList = [
        { mode: 'stun()', value : 'Stun' },
        { mode: 'disinegrate()' ,value : 'Disinegrate' },
        { mode: 'erase()', value : 'Erase' },
    ];
    $scope.menuState = { show: false };
    $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
        $scope.menuState.show = !$scope.menuState.show;
    };
    $scope.stun = function() {
        alert('Snorlax is stunned!');
    };
    $scope.disinegrate = function() {
        alert('Charizard used Disinegrate!');
    };
    $scope.erase = function() {
        alert('erased Sleep skill');
    };
});
```

If it's still unclear please do tell me.

Comment: What do you mean by "initiate" ng-click?

Comment: You need to use `data-ng-click="menu.mode()"`, but the mode property should point to a function. In your case i see it as a string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, when you define your menuList array, do not set mode to a string, but instead to the actual function

```
$scope.menuList = [
    { mode: $scope.stun, value : 'Stun' },
    { mode: $scope.disinegrate ,value : 'Disinegrate' },
    { mode: $scope.erase, value : 'Erase' },
];
```

Then in your markup:

```
data-ng-click="menu.mode()"
```

here is a [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/vwt0s545chZAmxkB6NTy?p=preview) to working code

Answer (score 0):

Define functions before assigning them to object.Assign them as

```
$scope.menuList = [
    { mode: $scope.stun, value : 'Stun' },
    { mode: $scope.disinegrate ,value : 'Disinegrate' },
    { mode: $scope.erase, value : 'Erase' },
];
```

and use them in html as

```
<ul>  
 <li data-ng-repeat="menu in menuList"><a href="" data-ng-click="menu.mode()">{{ menu.value }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

**View:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="DeathRayController">
  <button data-ng-click="toggleMenu()">Toggle Menu</button>
  <ul ng-show="menuState.show">
    <li data-ng-repeat="menu in menuList"><a href="" data-ng-click="menu.mode()">{{ menu.value }}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**controller:**

```
var showHide = angular.module('showHide', []);

showHide.controller('DeathRayController', function ($scope) {
// the idea is to display this on the <a ng-click="menu.mode()">
$scope.stun = function() {
    alert('Snorlax is stunned!');
};
$scope.disinegrate = function() {
    alert('Charizard used Disinegrate!');
};
$scope.erase = function() {
    alert('erased Sleep skill');
};
$scope.menuList = [
    { mode: $scope.stun, value : 'Stun' },
    { mode: $scope.disinegrate ,value : 'Disinegrate' },
    { mode: $scope.erase, value : 'Erase' },
];
$scope.menuState = { show: false };
$scope.toggleMenu = function() {
    $scope.menuState.show = !$scope.menuState.show;
};
```

});

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rVCV2/1/